# LibGDX - ShapeRenderer is too slow / Low FPS on Android

Tags: android, libgdx, conways-game-of-life

I just wrote Conway's Game of Life in Java and i wanted to test my application on my android phone (Nexus 4).
For testing, i draw a BitmapFont on my SpriteBatch showing me FPS, gyro, cells alive and other data.
On the PC, i have ~ 500 to 4000 FPS, depending on how fast my GOL-logic works. However, if i start it on android, the FPS drop to 10-15. If I turn off my ShapeRenderer (which is my main Class to render all the GOL-Rectangles) with the GOL-logic at almost full-speed, the FPS is constantly at 60 (i guess you can't turn off VSync on a Nexus 4).

So, here is my question:
Why is the ShapeRenderer so highly inefficient? What else should i use to render my Shapes?

I will post my (fairly simple) render code and a picture:

```
        this.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.getX_length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.getY_length(); j++) {


                if (cells[i][j].getState()){ // checks if the cell is dead or alive
                    this.setColor(new Color (0,0,0,1));
                    rect(i * size, j * size, size-gap, size-gap); // draws it.
                }
```

(http://s14.directupload.net/images/140929/qc3uu8ew.png)

Comment: I have no issues with ShapeRenderer on my Android phone. You could just render a small png texture using SpriteBatch.draw() rather than regenerating rectangles on every frame? I'm not sure which would be more efficient but it's worth a try.

Comment: First of all don't create a new Color object every frame for about a million times. Simply save the color in a variable and you are good to go. Else youll have alot of garbage collecting which reduces the performance. Moreover you create a tons of objects inside of the RAM which will reduce the performance too. I dont think that this is the issue but it meight chance something already. Show us the whole class. Maybe thtat helps.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I draw small .pngs now and use Color variables. On android, i have 60 FPS finally and on my PC the FPS-Rate increased for 50-100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the rectangles but I experienced the same Probelem with Circles. The Reoson that it takes so much time to draw a circle is that it draws a lot of single lines to form a circle.

See the source code for reference:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.java#L833